# Seq.filter and infinite seems counterintuitive

Tags: f#

I'm trying to understand the results of applying filters over infinite lists.  I'll need an explanation to understand what is happening under the covers.

```
let nums = Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.filter ((>) 0);;
nums |> Seq.take 0;; // of course, this works
nums |> Seq.take 1;; // this overflows
```

To my reading, line one means "start an infinite sequence at zero and filter out all values greater than zero (such as 1, 2, 3 etc...)".  Therefore, getting zero values returns an empty set.  Ok, makes sense.  But if we take one value, and that value would be zero which is clearly not greater than zero, why the overflow?

**Experimenting further:**

```
let nums = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i - 1) |> Seq.filter ((>) 0);;
nums |> Seq.take 1;; // this works and returns -1
nums |> Seq.take 2;; // this overflows
```

Again, as I read this, zero should be a valid value to which the sequence can iterate.

**Compound my confusion:**

```
let nums = Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.filter ((>=) 0);;
nums |> Seq.take 1;; // works, [0]
```

Maybe I can reconcile the behavior by assuming the filter actually means, "values are not valid UNLESS they are >= 0".  But that doesn't merit out:

```
let nums = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i - 1) |> Seq.filter ((>=) 0);;
nums |> Seq.take 1;; // works [-1]
nums |> Seq.take 2;; // works [-1, 0]
```

It cannot be the case that the filter defines ***valid*** values... for -1 is not >= 0 in the case of `filter ((>=) 0)`.

It cannot be the case that the filter defines ***invalid*** values... for 0 is not > 0 in the case of `filter ((>) 0)`.

Please unscramble this for me.

Comment: you should probably try `Seq.filter ((<) 0)` instead as `((>) 0)` is equal to `(fun n -> 0 > n)` and this should explain your problems ;)

Comment: Based on the answer, I can state this in English as, "generate an infinite sequence starting at zero and take one value such that zero is greater than that value".  I think I get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of how you're using the predicate it's quite confusing what it actually means. Let's solve that problem first, by pushing a finite sequance with known set of values by your filter.

```
> let input = [-5; 0; 5 ];;
val input : int list = [-5; 0; 5]

> let output = input |> Seq.filter ((>) 0) |> Seq.toList;;
val output : int list = [-5]
```

Wait, why is `-5` returned? That's because `(>) 0` does not actually mean `x > 0`, it means `(>) 0 x`, which is equivalent to `0 > x`. So your `Seq.filter ((>) 0)` means the same as `Seq.filter (fun i -> 0 > i)`:

```
> let output = input |> Seq.filter (fun i -> 0 > i) |> Seq.toList;;
val output : int list = [-5]
```

Now that we have that figured out, let's try looking into the overflow.

```
let nums = Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.filter ((>) 0);;
```

`Seq.initInfinite id` returns an infinite collection starting with `0` with next element equals to `prev + 1`.

```
> Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.take 5 |> Seq.toList;;
val it : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]  // this will keep going if you remove Seq.take
```

Now you're adding filter, which only returns element smaller than `0`. How many element like this there are? **None!**. So your filter will keep asking for next element out of `Seq.initInfinite` until you overflow `Integer` range and exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Sequences are lazily evaluated, so at first glance this behaviour seems a bit strange since you aren't calling toList, toArray etc.

In fact it's only overflowing because you're using F# interactive, which tries to print the first few elements of the sequence when you press return. It therefore attempts to iterate through your infinite sequence until it finds some items that match your predicate and never finds any, hence the overflow.